# "Reject and Edit" failed me in review audit. Why?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

I was reviewing a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5708909) which is clearly wrong and I chose to reject it and then edit the post. Why did I fail?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: wtf]

Comment: Maybe audits haven't been updated to handle "Reject and Edit" logic?

Comment: @Troyen, that was my first thought since it was the first time I saw the `Reject and Edit` option there.

Comment: Yes, it’s probably still equivalent to Edit as far as audits go (and Edit + uncheck “helpful” as far as suggested edit reviews in their entirety go). The suggested edit audit code will have to be edited. Perhaps edit audit audits will help in the future.

Comment: Related on MSO: [Reject and Edit response should not fail an audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270848/3622940)

Comment: here's another example of a question that could use some minor editing: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5727007

Comment: @JanDvorak, what's wrong with that? You rejected the edit and the audit passed you.

Comment: @SamRad well, I'd rather have rejected and edited instead. This way, I could only reject in the review window and never got to actually editing it, nor do I care now.

Comment: [This bug has been fixed now.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15455803)