# Reject and Edit on suggested edit review audits should allow me to edit the original post

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits, review-audits

Currently, clicking Reject and Edit in a suggested edit review audit simply passes the audit just like if the user would have clicked Reject. I guess that's not too bad compared to [how it worked first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239024/349538). However, if a user chooses Reject and Edit instead of simply Reject, it means that the original post can still be edited. I therefore think that clicking Reject and Edit on review audits should allow the user to edit the original post.

I can think of two possible ways of implementing this feature request, which I've illustrated with some pictures that I made in Paint:

1. Tell the user that it's an audit and then ask the user if they still want to edit it. This would look something like this:

   [image]
2. Let the user edit as soon as they click Reject and Edit, and show the passed review audit message when the user is editing. This would look something like this:

   [image]

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, although I don't think it's a very high priority.

Comment: So you want to actually edit the audit?  That defeats the purpose of that answer or question being an audit

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to edit the audit. I want to edit the post itself, discarding the changes suggested in the audit.

Comment: What purpose is there to allow the user to edit the question or answer if the edit will be thrown away since it's being performed through an audit.  Contributions that are audits, can still be modified outside of the audit, provided you can see them.

Comment: @Ramhound My edit won't be thrown away, it's the edit that was suggested in the audit that will be thrown away and be replaced by mine. Then my edit will be applied to the post just like if I would have rejected and edited a real suggested edit or would have edited the post outside of the review system.